# jquery and fs dont work together in angular electron app (using ngx-electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

So I have an angular app where I have jquery library and in the components, I have

```
included declare var $;
ngOnInit(){$(document).ready{....}}
```

and i have installed ngx-electron to import the fs library .

```
import {ElectronService} from 'ngx-electron'
constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { 
    this.fs = this._electronService.remote.require('fs');
}
```

Now for the ngx-electron to work I have to set the following in the main.js file:

```
webPreferences: { 
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
```

However, when I do this, jquery stops loading on the browser (Jquery is not defined). Without these web preferneces, jquery worked fine but this._electronService.remote returns null. How do I make both Jquery and fs (ngx-electron) work at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I went deep into the rabbit hole for the past 24 hours and have a better understanding of how angular and electron work together - and how the electron renderer works.

The solution to the problem was using preload.js as shown in this:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738

So a small addition to this - for it to work with angular inside a component rather than from index.html, we can skip the line in the comment above in index.html . Instead put that in your component. Additionally you will need to fetch the global window object into your component with const win = (window)

> main.js
> preload.js

```
Use the link above for both main.js and preload.js
```

> compontent.ts

```
const win = (<any>window)

ngOnInit(){
win.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
        console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
    });
win.api.send("toMain", "some data");
```

This solution works both from a security stand point as well as from the rendering stand point. I dont need to alter my angular app for jquery to work with electron. And further, any access to the fs object can be done from the main.js file and the result can be returned to the angular app via the apis rather than directly trying to access the file system(fs) from the angular app by setting nodeIntegration: true, contextIntegration:false etc. in the web preferences.
So, in summary, ngx-electron is not ideal as it depends on nodeIntegration to be set to true.